# Fetching the dataset for convolutional neural network ( CNN ) with TensorFlow 2.0 (python 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

I understand how fetch dataset from public TensorFlow Datasets (for example "mnist')

```
dataset = tfds.load( 'horses_or_humans' , split=tfds.Split.TRAIN )
```

How fetch dataset for my image dataset ?

Answer (score 0):

your question is somewhat inaudible, you can search in tensorflow datasets for get any database you want to use. TensorFlow Datasets is a collection of datasets ready to use, with TensorFlow or other Python ML frameworks, such as Jax. All datasets are exposed as tf.data.Datasets , enabling easy-to-use and high-performance input pipelines. To get started see the guide and our list of datasets. [See more](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2019/02/introducing-tensorflow-datasets.html) and [List of available datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/overview#all_datasets) .

Comment: Thanks for the quick response !

I have my own image dataset.
In the directory "My_dataset" there are two folders with images "class1" and "class2".
If I understand correctly, I have to use `DatasetBuilder` before

Comment: Or rather, I need [Writing custom datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/add_dataset)

Comment: This is a dictionary of this format : `{ 'image': Image(shape=(300, 300, 3), dtype=tf.uint8), 'label': ClassLabel(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, num_classes=2), }`